# GADMAdapterGoogleAdMobAds state = Not Ready;No such adapter in the application

Tags: admob, swift5, mobile-ad-mediation

I try to use mediation in my application and it only works for the adapters of AdColony, not the other networks I have added (without extra adapters required)

my code

```
    func prepareAdNetwork() {
    let ads = GADMobileAds.sharedInstance()
    
    ads.start { status in
        
        let adapterStatuses = status.adapterStatusesByClassName
              for adapter in adapterStatuses {
                let adapterStatus = adapter.value
                print("Adapter Name: %@, Description: %@, Latency: %f", adapter.key, adapterStatus.description, adapterStatus.latency)
              }
        
        self.adLoader = GADAdLoader(adUnitID: self.adUnitID, rootViewController: self.window?.rootViewController, adTypes: [.native], options: nil)
        
        self.adLoader.delegate = self
        

        self.configureAds()
        self.loadFullScreenAds()

    }
    
    
}
```

the configureAds is just sending the request

```
        if adLoader != nil {
        self.adLoader.load(GADRequest())
    }
```

the result

Adapter Name: %@, Description: %@, Latency: %f GADMAdapterGoogleAdMobAds <GADAdapterStatus: 0x120a6b940; state = Not Ready;No such adapter in the application.> 0.0
Adapter Name: %@, Description: %@, Latency: %f GADMediationAdapterAdColony <GADAdapterStatus: 0x162505140; state = Ready> 0.5974940061569214
Adapter Name: %@, Description: %@, Latency: %f GADMobileAds <GADAdapterStatus: 0x120a6ba00; state = Ready> 0.07822108268737793
Adapter Name: %@, Description: %@, Latency: %f GADMediationAdapterFacebook <GADAdapterStatus: 0x162537000; state = Ready> 1.151913046836853

I guess the error is the reason for the mediation to not work properly.
However, I have gone through the tutorial multiple times and I don't know what I am doing wrong.
It seems that I am missing a pod file which I have to include but don't know which one

the currently included ones (and updated today) are:

```
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', '~> 7.11.0'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationAdColony'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook'
```

Any idea how what is wrong? Normal ads and from adcolony work fine...